# SQL group by one column, sort by another and transponse a third

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table, which is actually the minimal example of the result of multiple joined tables. I now would like to group by 'person_ID' and get all the 'value' entries in one row, sorted after the feature_ID.

```
person_ID  | feature_ID | value
123        | 1          | 1.1
123        | 2          | 1.2
123        | 3          | 1.3
123        | 4          | 1.2
124        | 1          | 1.0
124        | 2          | 1.1
...
```

The result should be:

```
123  |  1.1  |  1.2  | 1.3  |  1.2
124  |  1.0  |  1.1  | ...
```

There should exist an elegant SQL query solution, which I can neither come up with, nor find it.

For fast reconstruction that would be the example data:

```
create table example(person_ID integer, feature_ID integer, value float);
insert into  example(person_ID, feature_ID, value) values
  (123,1,1.1),
  (123,2,1.2),
  (123,3,1.3),
  (123,4,1.2),
  (124,1,1.0),
  (124,2,1.1),
  (124,3,1.2),
  (124,4,1.4);
```

Edit: Every person has 6374 entries in the real life application.

I am using a PostgreSQL 8.3.23 database, but I think that should probably be solvable with standard SQL.

Comment: Is the column value `feature_ID` fixed from 1 to 4?

Comment: If you mean that every person has the same amount of rows in this table, than yes. Though in real life it runs from 0 to 6373.

Answer (score 0):

Data bases aren't much at transposing.  There is a nebulous column growth issue at hand, I mean how does the data base deal with a variable number of columns?  It's not a spread sheet.

This transposing of sorts is normally done in the report writer, not in SQL.

... or in a program, like in php.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic cross tab in sql only by procedure, see:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/